# Replace multiple strings of unknown content, length

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace multiple delimiters within a single string with a break tag, but the delimiters are not always the exact same or of the same length.  The delimiters do follow this pattern when within the string: #[some number];#

For example, I want

```
49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart
```

to become

```
Simpson, Homer
Simpson, Bart
```

And I want

```
49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart;#101;#Simpson, Lisa
```

to become

```
Simpson, Homer
Simpson, Bart
Simpson, Lisa
```

I was using the following to remove the first [number];# from the string, but I'm not sure how to replace the rest.

```
peopleString = peopleString.substring(peopleString.indexOf(";#") + 2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do the numbers mean anything or...?

Comment: The numbers are the ID of the person, but I don't care about them for this example.  They can be be any number of digits 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses regex after your initial replacement of the first  `[number];#`,

Some more info about regular expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

```js
var replacement = '<br>';
var doReplace = function(str) {
  str = str.substring(str.indexOf(";#") + 2);
  return str.replace(/;#[0-9]+;#/g, replacement);
}

document.write(doReplace('49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart'));
document.write('<br>---<br>')
document.write(doReplace('49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart;#101;#Simpson, Lisa'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this may to use the string's [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function and a regex.

```
var data = "49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart;#101;#Simpson, Lisa";
var parsed_data = data.replace(/#?\d+;#/g, "");
```

This regex, /#?\d+;#/g, finds:

1. #? : tries to find that first pound sign, but its ok if it is missing.
2. \d+ : one or more digits. This will match the numbering.
3. ; matches ;
4. # : matches the last pound sign.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent candidate for the Regular Expression replace function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Look into using the replace function and the Global flag to replace all instances of your delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to do that.

you could try with sample

```
var string = '49;#Simpson, Homer;#45;#Simpson, Bart;#101;#Simpson, Lisa'
string.replace('/;*#*\d+;#*/g','');
console.log('result',string);
```